# How to use 'magnific-popup' with Angular

Tags: angular, magnific-popup

I have implemented  the Magnific popup almost successfully here:
https://github.com/orchidea90/Popup
https://orchidea90.github.io/Popup/,
 but I need a help with my .ts file. How to make it simpler and without so many repetitions.

https://github.com/orchidea90/Popup/blob/master/src/app/menu/menu.component.ts

I'm still learning. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is create an array with the items data, then in your template use a ngFor to to show wach item.

So in your .ts you create the array ( in OnInit ).

I also created a variable (imageFolderPath) to hold the common path for all images.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.imageFolderPath = './assets/images/';

    this.aMenuItems = [
        { imagePath: 'menu-image1.png', title: 'American Breakfast', ingredients: 'Tomato / Eggs / Sausage', price: 25 },
        { imagePath: 'menu-image2.png', title: 'Self-made Salad', ingredients: 'Green / Fruits / Healthy', price: 18 },
        { imagePath: 'menu-image3.jpg', title: 'Chinese Noodle', ingredients: 'Pepper / Chicken / Vegetables', price: 34 },
        { imagePath: 'menu-image4.png', title: 'Rice Soup', ingredients: 'Green / Chicken', price: 28 },
        { imagePath: 'menu-image5.png', title: 'Deli Burger', ingredients: 'Beef / Fried Potatoes', price: 46 },
        { imagePath: 'menu-image6.png', title: 'Big Flat Fried', ingredients: 'Pepper / Crispy', price: 30 },
    ]
}
```

in your html, you use only one block to define the html, *ngFor will create 1 for each item of the array.

```
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let item of aMenuItems">
               <!-- MENU THUMB -->
               <div class="menu-thumb">
                    <a [href]="imageFolderPath + item.imagePath" class="image-popup" title="item.title">
                         <img [src]="imageFolderPath + item.imagePath" class="img-responsive" alt="item.title">

                         <div class="menu-info">
                              <div class="menu-item">
                                   <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
                                   <p>{{item.ingredients}}</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="menu-price">
                                   <span>${{item.price}}</span>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                    </a>
               </div>
          </div>
```